# Report on email about low disk space

Tags: hard-drive, email, disk-space, report

I would like to know if there's a special tool or a way to write a script, which will monitor the left free disk space, and when it's lower that the value I put as a default, this tool will generate a report/warning and send it to my email.

With all the above I want to be able to control the Hard Disk space on my VM without going there, but just via having an email warning.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include details of your operating system.

Comment: I'm pretty certain I've seen a dupe here that gave a one line script to do this - will try and find it

Answer (score 0):

I'm working for JAM Software and we have a product called ServerSentinel that could help you here.

It's a monitoring tool that comes with a lot of sensors. One of them should solve your problem. Simply look for the ServerSentinel Disk Space Sensor.

I'm a developer of ServerSentinel, so if you have any questions, just drop me a line, I'm happy to help.